# Running gcov on shared library from python script

Tags: python, c, linux, shared-libraries

I am facing an issue with running gcov on shared library from python script.

I have the following scenario where i build my library:

1. Compile a set of files (file1.c, file2.c) into a statically linked lib(.a). I use ar utility to do this and all the files are compiled using following options:

   > -static -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -coverage
2. build a .so file using some other files (say file3.c) and the above specified .a file. I use the same options again while compiling and linking.
3. Load the .so in python script and execute.

Issue :
The coverage file that is generated contains code coverage only for file3.c. Files that are part of the .a library are not shown in the coverage report.

Am i missing any option while linking .a here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue. 
I was not picking up all the .gcda files for generating the report.
Use -object-directory option to search for all gcda files.

[GCOV man page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov)

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure you provide python wrapper in your c-code.

It can be achieved by using [BOOST.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/) or [SWIG](http://www.swig.org).

Comment: You can refer to [this page](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Introduction_nn8) for some detail of SWIG approach

Comment: Not sure what you mean actually my providing python wrapper here. I am able to call the methods in library successfully. The issue is only with running gcov.