# Coverage of C++ Code called via Pybind from Python Test

Tags: python, code-coverage, pybind11

Currently working with a legacy codebase that creates a number of Pybind modules and tests most of the exposed C++ code via Python tests.

Is it possible to determine code coverage of the C++ code via Python tests? My understanding of C++ coverage is that you need to have a compiled test executable with the object files that can be run in order to gather the coverage data (the resultant `gcda` files). The problem here is that the Python tests don't call a test executable, they use the compiled `.so` files via the Pybind module.

Is it possible to generate coverage data via Pybind and `.so` files?

If it helps we're using Bazel and I've created a simple sandbox environment with a basic `pybind_library` target and `py_test` target. I can compile the `pybind_library` (which wraps a `cc_binary` target) with the coverage flags and generate the `gcno` files, but when the `py_test` target executes it doesn't generate any `gcda` files but is definitely using the compiled `.so` library.

Answer (score 1):

Nota bene: all of this is based on readings on internet. I have no experience in this specific matter (gcov on dynamic libraries drived by python tests).

**My initial thought** on this question was that is not possible because :

1. In [gcov documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-Intro.html), it is said that

> gcov works only on code compiled with GCC. It is not compatible with any other profiling or test coverage mechanism

2. it is also said that [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712908/gcov-producing-gcda-output-from-shared-library)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Freestanding-Environments.html) :

> Normally, when the application exits, the gcov information is stored to .gcda files. There is one file per translation unit instrumented for profiling or test coverage. The function __gcov_exit(), which stores the gcov information to a file, is called by a global destructor function for each translation unit instrumented for profiling or test coverage. It runs at process exit.

For this to happen, you need to let the overall test coverage application (the Python tests in your case) know how to gather gcov information and store it in .gcda files. This is done with the `--coverage` option you pass at link time when you link your library (.so) to your python test. If your linker is not capable of that (does not know the `--coverage` option) your are done.

3. To make gcov work with dynamic libraries, you have to pass the `--coverage` option to the linker as explained in this post : [Is it possible code coverage of a shared library using gcov?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385590/is-it-possible-code-coverage-of-a-shared-library-using-gcov)

For all these reasons I believed what your are trying to achieve is not possible.

**However**, the post [Running gcov on shared library from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598416/running-gcov-on-shared-library-from-python-script) suggests there would be a way to achieve what you want to do. A few tracks to find your way :

1. Make sure there is absolutely no .gcda files anywhere. People having tried to do so ended up to find .gcda file elsewhere (in .lib directory where .so file is instead of with the source files). See for instance [gcov producing gcda output from shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712908/gcov-producing-gcda-output-from-shared-library) and [this thread](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2010-09/msg00134.html)
2. Don't forget to add the `--coverage` option when you build your python bindings, in CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS.

We would need more details on your setup to move on. That's all I can say so far.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the following file, `func.cpp`:

```cpp
// func.cpp

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int func(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return 42;

    return a + b;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(_lib, m)
{
    m.def("func", &func, py::arg("a"), py::arg("b"));
}
```

We can compile this as follows with `g++`:

```bash
g++ func.cpp -shared -o _lib.so `pybind11-config --includes` -lstdc++ --coverage -fPIC
```

You may also need the `-fprofile-abs-path` flag when stuff gets moved around a lot. I ran into this issue when using Meson for the [PyVRP](https://github.com/PyVRP/PyVRP/) project, but you may be able to do without as in this small example.

We now have a native extension module `_lib.so` and a `_lib.so-func.gcno` notes file. Let's write some tests in the `test_func.py` file:

```py
# test_func.py

from _lib import func


def test_special_case():
    assert func(0, 1) == 42
    assert func(0, 10) == 42


def test_regular_case():
    assert func(1, 2) == 3
    assert func(2, 4) == 6
```

When we run `pytest test_func.py`, we should now also have a `_lib.so-func.gcda` file that contains coverage data. Grepping that for an overview gets us:

```bash
>>>gcov -H _lib.so-func.gcda | grep func.cpp -A1
File '[...]/func.cpp'
Lines executed:100.00% of 7
```

Now that we have the `gcda` files, further processing can produce much prettier reports, including line coverage.